# Can i know if the caller retained a copy of the shared pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, shared-ptr

Let's say I have a function `f` like this:

```
class MyClass {
};

boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> f(/*other input parameters*/) {
  static boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> p;
  if (!p.get() || /*Test if somebody else has a copy of my pointer*/) {
    p.reset(new MyClass() );
  }

  /*Do other stuff*/

  return p;
}
```

Can I check if the caller retained a copy of my pointer? If I release my pointer, and he also releases his pointer, will be the memory released?

Comment: You shouldn't want to know, this defeats the whole purpose of shared pointers. As soon as the last owner releases the pointer, the destructor will be called.

Comment: @Vlad I had a use case (with MyClass being a support class containing also a buffer that could be reallocated depending on the input parameters, with the caller that could send a pointer to a MyClass already previously created, and with the function returning the pointer to MyClass so that the caller could decide if to use it for the next call), but probably it's better if I do things in a different way. :)

Comment: Why not make `MyClass` immutable, and allocate a new `MyClass` when you need to?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I check if the caller retained a copy of my pointer?

No, and as Vlad said, you really shouldn't want to know. There is this `use_count` function, but boost warns against using it.

> Notes: use_count() is not necessarily efficient. Use only for debugging and testing purposes, not for production code.

As for your second question,

> If I release my pointer, and he also releases his pointer, will be the memory released?

the answer is yes, provided the ownership was shared only between these two instances.

Comment: I just saw use_count()... Just to understand, would that work? In which way do you expect it will be inefficient? Will it be checking all memory in use?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `boost::shared_ptr` (and `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, and in C++11 `std::shared_ptr`) is that when then last bit of code holding on to a copy of the shared pointer goes out of existence, the memory is released.

[ EDIT: COMPLETELY INCORRECT ANALYSIS REMOVED ]

Comment: Regarding point 5: Being the variable static, I doubt "my" copy gets destroyed. Regarding point 2: the second time the function is called, that test is important.

Comment: Sorry; I missed the `static` completely. Please disregard my answer. [ Edited the answer to remove mistake. ]

Answer (score 0):

You could override the global `new` and `delete` operators and check whether the memory pointed to by the pointer is still occupied. If so and you have reset your own shared pointers pointing to the memory, then the only conclusion can be, that the user has not reset his. This is not necessarily efficient or recommended though. The pointer contained by a `shared_ptr` also does not necessarily point to memory allocated by `new` due to the custom deleter feature.